# Looking to align text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find the answer to this, but not coming up with anything in a search.  Basically, my output will look like:

Name: Joe Smith

Address: 555 Main Street

Title: Chief cook and bottlewasher

Right now, it doesn't look nice because the results aren't aligned. Like, "Joe" and "555" and "Chief" should all be left-aligned evenly, rather than simply following the colon by a space. What's the best way to accomplish this in CSS?

Comment: table if it's a tabular data, else use separate containers for both and float them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. This is one way of doing it.

HTML

```
My Profile<br />
    <span class="label">Name</span><span class='values'>: Joe Smith</span><br />
    <span class="label">Address</span><span class='values'>: 555 Main Street</span><br />
    <span class="label">Title</span><span class='values'>: Chief cook and bottlewasher</span><br />
```

CSS

```
.label { display:inline-block; width:100px; text-align:left;}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3FFVk/)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I'm all about searching before asking, but for some reason I just couldn't think of the term for what I was looking for, without actually demonstrating!

Answer (score 0):

There's no "best way" as you can accomplish this in a number of ways, but here's how you can do it using `dl`, `dt` and `dd`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcPK4/)

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Joe Smith</dd>
    <dt>Address</dt>
    <dd>55 Main Street</dd>
    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Chief cook and bottlewasher</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dt {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px /* Set the width of the first column here */
}
dd {
    display:inline
}
dd::after {
    content:'\A';
    white-space:pre
}
```